# How to open dotnet-core CLI project in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-2017, dotnet-cli

I have been developing a simple application using dotnet Core (for an API) and Angular2 for the purpose of learning both.

**I created the project using Yeoman on the command line** and have been happily coding away in Visual Studio Code (on Windows). All seems to hang together well and it's been an enjoyable experience.

I thought I might try out Visual Studio 2017 and see what the experience of developing a dotnet Core project in VS is like for a while.

**However, having installed VS2017 and cloned the project from github I am unsure how to proceed. I can't see any way to restore/build/run the project.**

After cloning the repo, I see my project displayed in the Solution Explorer with the project.json file visible. However, Debug | Start is greyed out. I read somewhere about VS2017 needing to convert project.json to the new (old?) XML format and also I have a feeling I am missing a .sln file.

I would appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### If your project has an `.xproj` file

1. Open Visual Studio.
2. File > Open > Project/Solution.
3. Open the `xxx.xproj` for your solution.

#### If your project lacks an `.xproj` file

1. Install .NET Core SDK [Preview 3 or higher](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/preview4-download.md).
2. Open a command prompt at your project's directory.
3. Run `dotnet migrate`.
4. Open the resulting `.csproj` in Visual Studio 2017.

#### Troubleshooting

View migration help with `dotnet migrate -h`.

If you have a `global.json` file, update its SDK version before running `migrate`. E.g.

```
{
    "sdk": {
        "version": "1.0.0-preview4-004233"
    }
}
```

View installed SDK versions with `dir 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\'`.

Update Visual Studio 2017 and its installer. On my machine, the above works with Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017 RC Version `15.0.26014.0 D15REL`.

Update .NET Core SDK. On my machine, the above works with SDK `1.0.0-preview4-004233`.

Comment: Yup, this worked .. thanks! I am now struggling with build problems and VS2017 having seemingly broken dotnet run from cli but all that is beyond the scope of this question!