# How to Open .NET Core CLI Project in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2017, dotnet-cli

For one of my classes this semester, I am required to use .NET Core 1.1 and version 1.0.0-preview2-003177 of the CLI tools. How can I open such a project in Visual Studio 2017? I have found solutions that work for 1.0.0-preview4-004233, but I am not allowed to upgrade my project to the newer version due to my professor's requirements.

Comment: I think you will get your answer from this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41408500/how-to-open-dotnet-core-cli-project-in-visual-studio-2017

Comment: Then please make a constructive conversation with your professor and let him/her understand that preview 2 is too old and now everything changes with latest RC build, like Visual Studio 2017 RC shipped today.

Comment: @Pedo, I found that answer, but it requires I upgrade my project, which I cannot do.

Comment: @LexLi, my professor is perfectly aware of the changes. I believe he is requiring this because some students are using older versions of Visual Studio that are less compatible, but I'm not really sure of his reasoning. All I do know is that he requires this version, but I cannot get it to work with Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: If I were in his/her shoes, I would ask all students to use Visual Studio Code at this moment, which ships always the latest .NET Core via the C# extension, and wait till Visual Studio 2017 and .NET Core SDK 1.0 official release to save the day. In your case, still VSCode and the dotnet CLI of preview 2 should be enough.

Comment: @LexLi, thank you. He recommended Visual Studio Code, but he also said that Visual Studio itself has better features, so I was hoping to use that. So is it simply not possible to use preview 2 with VS2017?